How to make my code find words instead of paragraphs
I have asked this question before but since then I've changed the code some and have additional variations so I am making a new question.
I am working on a tag to remove repeating text in  the address field. This is for Word VBA. When grabbing the text from the XML to populate the document, if it finds the tag it applies the code to that region.
Here's some examples of what i am working with:
Bob Ross Bob Ross
123 Random Street
123 Random Street
Random State, RC 12345-1234
Random State, RC 12345

Bob Ross
123 Random Street
Random State, RC 12345-1234
Bob Ross
123 Random Street
Random State, RC 12345-1234

Bob Ross
123 Random Street
Bob Ross
Random State, RC 12345-1234
123 Random Street
Random State, RC 12345-1234

So I want the code to change variations like the ones before to this:
Bob Ross
123 Random Street
Random State, RC 12345-1234

Here is what i have been working with so far:
Dim currentRange As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim paraToWork As Paragraph
Dim diffWords As Variant
Dim dupDictionary as New Scripting.Dictionary

Set currentRange = BWFinds.FindAndReturnRange("\<[Dd][Dd][Tt]\>*\</\1\>")
    If not currentRange Is Nothing Then
        For each paraToWork In currentRange.Paragraphs
        diffWords = paraToWork
            If diffWords <> vbCr Then
                If Not dupDictionary.Exists(diffWords) Then dupDictionary.Add diffWords, New Scripting.Dictionary
                dupDictionary(diffWords).Add dupDictionary(diffWords).Count + 1, paraToWork
            End If
        Next
    End If

For Each diffWords in dupDictionary
    For i = 2 To dupDictionary(diffWords).Count
    dupDictionary(diffWords)(i).Range.Delete
Next

It only works when there's two paragraphs that are the same. I want to change this to look for words rather than paragraphs in a range in order remove duplicate words, I have seen that I can make the range into an array of words/ string? I just don't know how to implement that and i would love to learn how to do so, any help would be greatly appreciated.
For a situation where New York City, New York might happen, I can add it as a key in Scripting.Dictionary in order to prevent it form getting deleted. BWFinds is a form, it contains various methods I use.

You could investigate the Range.Words collection, but bear in mind that what Word considers to be a "word" may not coincide with what you need to consider as a word.

How should that work? If you look for words with multiple occurecnces, "Random" would be removed from either the street or the city ... don't think that is what you want ...
